# String to HTML paragraphs in Java with Regex

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a string that needs to be formatted for HTML with `<p></p>` tags. That is to say STRING->HTML conversion, and a simple case of only converting to paragraph.

```
public stringToHtml() {
    INPUT_STRING = "HEADING 1 \r Some Text \r\r HEADING 2 \r Some more Text \r\r";
    String pattern = "^(.+)$";
    String htmlString = pdf.get("TextArea").replaceAll(pattern, "<p>\1</p>");
```

However the resulting htmlString appears unchanged.

Works on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vMaoxi/1)

**UPDATE**

Tried $1 - but same result (no `<p>` tags)

```
String htmlString = pdf.get("TextArea").replaceAll(pattern, "<p>$1</p>");
```

Comment: A backreference in Java regex replacement patterns is formed with `$`, `$1`.

Comment: [Here we go again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7694740)

Comment: Except, @Juan - this is not trying to parse HTML, it is trying to _insert_ HTML into a plain-text string.

Comment: You can do it without regex with a simple replace function. Simply replace the new lines with `</p><p>` and then wrap the entire string with `<p>` and `</p>`. If you want to keep the new lines, then replace them with `</p>\r<p>`.